# Problem in understanding how colors are applied to each pixel

Tags: image-processing

I'm new to action recognition and anything related to image processing. I'm studying a paper about image processing. It is about action recognition based on human pose estimation. Here is a summary of how it works:

> We first run a state-of-the-art human pose estimator [4] in every
>   frame and obtain heatmaps for every human joint. These heatmaps encode
>   the probabilities of each pixel to contain a particular joint. We
>   colorize these heatmaps using a color that depends on the relative
>   time of the frame in the video clip. For each joint, we sum the
>   colorized heatmaps over all frames to obtain the PoTion representation
>   for the entire video clip.

So for each joint *j* in frame *t*, it extracts a heatmap H^t_j[x, y] that is the likelihood of pixel (x, y) containing joint j at frame t. The resolution of this heatmap is denoted by W*H.

My first question: What is a heatmap exactly? I wanted to be sure whether heatmap is a probability matrix in which, for example, the element in (1,1) contains a number which is an indicator of the probability that (1,1) pixel may contain the joint.

In the next step this heatmap is colorized with *C* channels which *C* shows the number of colors for visualizing each pixel. Here the idea is to use the same color for the joint heatmaps of a frame.

> We start by presenting the proposed colorization scheme for 2 channels
>   (C = 2). For visualization we can for example use red and green colors
>   for channel 1 and 2. The main idea is to colorize the first frame in
>   red, the last one in green, and the middle one with equal proportion
>   (50%) of green and red. The exact proportion of red and green is a
>   linear function of the relative time t, i.e., t−1/T−1 , see Figure 2
>   (left). For C = 2, we have o(t) = (t−1/T−1 , 1−(t−1/T−1). The
>   colorized heatmap of joint j for a pixel (x, y) and a channel *c* at
>   time *t* is given by:
>
> [image: equation]

And here is figure 2 which is mentioned in the context:

[image: pic]

My problem is that I cannot figure out whether this equation ( o(t) = (t−1/T−1 , 1−(t−1/T−1) ) represents the degree of one color (i.e red) in a frame or it shows the proportion of both of these colors. If it is used for each color channel separately, What does o_red(t) = (1/6 , 5/6) means when the number of frames (T) is equal to 7?

Or if it used for both channels, since the article says that the first frame is colored red and the last frame is colored green, how we can interpret o(1) = (0,1) if the first element indicates the proportion of red and the second one the proportion of green? As far as I can understand it means the first frame is colored green not red!

Answer (score 2):

In this concept there is a subtle relationship between time and pixel positions.

*As far as I know:* This kind of heatmap is for involving Time in your image. The purpose is to show the movement of a moving object which is captured by a video, in only one image, so every pixel of the image that is related to the fixed (unmoving) objects of the scene (like background pixels) get to be zero (black). In contrast, if in the video, the moving object pass from a pixel position, that corresponding pixel in the **image**, will be colorful and it's color depends on the number (time) of the frame that moving object has been seen in the pixel.

For example consider we have a completely black curtain in front of the camera and we are filming. We get a 1-second video which is made from 10 frames. At the first moment (frame 1) a very tiny white ball comes into the scene and get captured at pixel (1,1) in frame 1. then at frame two , that small ball got captured at pixel (1,2), and so on. At the end when we stop filming at frame 10, ball will be seen at pixel (1,10). Now we have 10 frames, which one of them has a white pixel at different position and we want to show the whole process in only one image, so 10 pixels of that image will be colorful (pixels: (1,1), (1,2),(1,3),...,(1,10)) and the other pixels are black.

With the formula you mentioned, the color of each pixel is computed according to the related frame number (which the ball got captured):

```
T=10 # 10 frames

pixel (1,1) got the white ball at frame 1 so its color would be ((0/9),1-(0/9)) which means the green channel has a zero value in that pixels and the red channel has 1 value so this pixel looks completely red.

pixel (1,2) got the white ball at frame 2 so its color would be (1/9 , 8/9), and  this pixels is more red than green.

... # continue so on for other 7 pixels

pixel (1,10) got the white ball at frame 2 so its color would be (1 , 0), and  this pixels is completely green.
```

Now at the if you look at the image, you see a colorful line which is 10-pixel long and it is red at the beginning and its color gradually changes to green as it goes to the end (10th pixel). WHICH means the ball moved from pixel one to pixel 10 during that 1 second video.

(If I were unclear at any point of the explanation, please comment and I will elaborate)

Comment: Thanks, I understood your explanation, but the problem is that I didn't find out what are the values in heatmap? Is that a matrix? If so, what are the values? Are they probabilities or what?

Comment: @helen It's just an image, a 2D matrix with a height and width same as the video frames. It's values are not probability, it's a float image (float images have a pixel values between 0 and 1). The changes in pixel values are just for better visualization.

Comment: So what does it mean "These heatmaps encode the probabilities of each pixel to contain a particular joint."?

Comment: @helen As I'm concerned it's a little twist in the definition of the concept, and I wouldn't use this word for explanation such notion. Although we can somehow consider the pixel value as probability because "zero" value at a pixel means the zero probability of passing the object from that pixel, but you can ignore the "probability" word for this matter and all the results would be reasonable for you